# Find $u\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(u) = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2}, 5^{1/3})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am having trouble finding such a $u$.  My instincts at first told me to do the obvious thing and let $u = 2^{1/2}5^{1/3}$ but $u^{2} = \left(2^{1/2}5^{1/3}\right)^{2} = 2\cdot5^{2/3}$ but we want $\frac{1}{2}u^{2} = 5^{1/3}$ right??  Any hints on how to approach the exercise?

Then the next part ask to describe how you would find all $w\in\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2}, 5^{1/3})$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(w) = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2}, 5^{1/3})$ I have no approach on this one except to possible look at linear combinations of the basis terms but dont know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the [proof](http://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/MATH404-PrimElem.pdf) of the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  I don't recall covering this particular theorem in class, so I wasn't too sure how to approach that part of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

> we want $\frac{1}{2} u^2 = 5^{1/3}$ right?

We just want $5^{1/3}$ to be in this field *somewhere*. You've shown it contains $5^{2/3}$: try squaring that.

Comment: This is true, thanks.  Well that finishes the first part, as $\frac{1}{10}u^{3} = 2^{1/2}$ and $\frac{1}{20}u^{4} = 5^{1/3}$ right?